# Sumifs between two numbers across different dataframes

Tags: r, sum, plyr

I have two data frames. One with a "from" and "to" intervals as follows;

```
Intervals <- data.frame("From" = c(0.0000,0.0069,0.0139,0.0208,0.0278,0.0347,0.0417,0.0486,0.0556,0.0625,0.0694,0.0764,0.0833),
                        "To" = c(0.0410,0.0479,0.0549,0.0618,0.0688,0.0757,0.0826,0.0896,0.0965,0.1035,0.1104,0.1174,0.1243))
```

and the second data frame is:

```
x <- data.frame("Dummy" = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0), 
                "Dummy Time" = c(0,0,0.006944444,0.006944444,0.010416667,0.010416667,0.013888889,0.013888889,0.020833333,0.024305556,0.027777778,0.03125,0.03125))
```

So I basically want to do a sumifs in R of the dummy variable if the dummy time falls between the From and To (or equal to) in the interval df. This is easy in excel but im pretty new to R.

The cbind wont work because Intervals and x are different rows. Basically the intervals are just the standard day and I'm hoping to create a new column on intervals to show the sum of dummys that incur during that time period

Comment: What is your wxpected output

Answer (score 0):

The most transparent way I can think to do this is:

```
n_interval = nrow(Intervals)
Intervals$DummySum = numeric(n_interval)
for(i in 1:n_interval) {
  ind_i = x$DummyTime >= Intervals$From[i] & x$DummyTime < Intervals$To[i]
  Intervals$DummySum[i] = sum(x$Dummy[ind_i])
}
```

This simply loops through all of the intervals, identifies the Dummies that are within each, and sums up the values.

If you don't like `for` loops, you can use `sapply`:

```
Intervals$DummySum = 
  sapply(1:nrow(Intervals), function(i) sum(
    x$Dummy[
      x$DummyTime >= Intervals$From[i] & x$DummyTime < Intervals$To[i]
      ]
  ))
```

Finally, you could turn this into a more general function like so:

```
sum_in_intervals = function(interval_start, interval_end, times, values, na.rm = FALSE) {
  stopifnot(length(interval_start) == length(interval_end))
  stopifnot(length(times) == length(values))

  return(
    sapply(1:length(interval_start), function(i) sum(
      values[
        times >= interval_start[i] & times < interval_end[i]
      ], 
      na.rm = na.rm
    ))
  )
}

Intervals$DummySum = sum_in_intervals(Intervals$From, Intervals$To, x$DummyTime, x$Dummy)
```